# Format time with timezone short format

Tags: javascript

I want to display the time in the user local timezone with the following format

```
hh:mm AM/PM timezone-name

eg: 11:00 PM CEST, 11:00 PM ICT
```

I have tried 2 options

```
// 11:00 PM Indochina Time
new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
        timeZoneName: "long"
})

// 11:00 PM GMT +7
new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
        timeZoneName: "short"
})
```

However, I don't want to show the time in GMT and the long version displays a really long text. I would like more shortcut text like

```
11:00 PM ICT (not Indochina Time)
11:00 PM CEST (not Central European Summer Time)
```

Comment: I believe that you need the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) instead of the `Date.toLocaleTimeString`